# $\ln(n+a)-\ln(n-a)=2(\frac an+\frac{a^3}{3n^3}+\frac{a^5}{5n^5}+\dots)$

Tags: logarithms, power-series

Show that
$$\ln(n+a)-\ln(n-a)=2\left(\frac an+\frac{a^3}{3n^3}+\frac{a^5}{5n^5}+\dots\right)$$
I tried writing
$$\ln(n+a)-\ln(n-a)=\ln\frac{n+a}{n-a}=\ln\left(1+\frac{2a}{n-a}\right)$$
and then applying the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$ but couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with
$$
 \ln (n+a) = \ln n + \ln \left( 1 + \frac an \right) =  \ln n + 
 \frac an - \frac 12 \left(\frac an \right)^2 + 
  \frac 13 \left(\frac an \right)^3 -  \frac 14 \left(\frac an \right)^4
 + \ldots \, ,
$$
using the MacLaurin series for $\ln (1+x)$.
Then do the same for $\ln (n-a)$ and combine the results.

Note that you need $n > 0$ and $|a| < n$ for these developments.

Answer (score 1):

We know that 
$$\log(n+a)-\log(n-a)=\log n+\log\left(1+\frac an\right)-\log n-\log\left(1-\frac an\right)=\\=\log\left(1+\frac an\right)-\log\left(1-\frac an\right)$$
Then using Taylor series we have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}a^k}{kn^k}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(-a)^k}{kn^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}a^k}{kn^k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a^k}{kn^k}=\color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a^{k+1}}{(2k+1)n^{2k+1}}}$$